# getting an array of images to collection view

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

I am trying to get an array of the images in my documents directory for displaying in a `UICollectionView` I am having trouble getting the actual array of images. I have spent some time trying to google this but most people seem to be getting their images from app bundle. I need my images to come from documents.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
  func getImageArray() {
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    if let dirPath          = paths.first
    {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("Images")
        let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)

        imageArray.append(image)
        print(imageURL)
    }

}
```

I am quite new to swift so the answer is probably obvious. could someone point me in the right direction or tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: You try to create an UIImage from an URL that points to a dictionary.

Comment: Okay, so I need an array of URLs which would point to each image in my directory? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to read directory contents , then individually loop for creating the images from urls

```
do {
    let allImages = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("Images") 
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: allImages.path) 
    for con in directoryContents { 
      let img = URL(fileURLWithPath:allImages).appendingPathComponent(con) 
      let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.path) 
      imageArray.append(image)
   }
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```